# ruby on rails ch10: command create errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Listing 10.3 Ruby on Rails tutorial - RED

When I’ve used command before 10.2 tutorial

```
rails generate migration add_activation_to_users \
➢   activation_digest:string activated:boolean activated_at:datetime
```

I’ve got as below, what am i doing wrong ?

```
$ rails generate migration add_activation_to_users \ 
activation_digest:string activated:boolean activated_at:datetime
      invoke  active_record
    conflict    db/migrate/20160425232958_add_activation_to_users.rb
Another migration is already named add_activation_to_users: /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/db/migrate/20160425203345_add_activation_to_users.rb. Use --force to replace this migration or --skip to ignore conflicted file.
```

But those lines are not exactly the same even so inside is the same:

1
[time_stamp]_add_activation_to_user.rb
2
220138948390_add_activation_to_use.rb

inside those files as below:

class AddRememberDigestToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration

def change

```
add_column :users, :remember_digest, :string
```

end

end

Is something wrong with that?

Comment: You must have done that step already. Are you sure this is the first time in this project? Have a look in `db/migrations` to see what's there.

Comment: I have as below under: db/migrate/[timestamp]_add_activation_to_users.rb and the same under(#is not exact): db/migrate/206543088_add_activation_to_users.rb

class AddActivationToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change

    add_column :users, :activation_digest, :string

    add_column :users, :activated, :boolean, default: false

    add_column :users, :activated_at, :datetime

  end
end
Is it right?

Comment: If you have more to add, which is great, it's often easier to amend your question and put it there as the code formatting helps readability considerably. That's a migration. The problem is you have two with the same name but different version numbers.

Comment: I have the same file as on example under:
db/migrate/[timestamp]_add_activation_to_users.rb db/migrate/206543088_add_activation_to_users.rb
So, should I ignore it?

Comment: You right. How can I amend the code? I could see only option "Answer your question" - which is no true because I have no answer yet.

Comment: There should be an `edit` link there somewhere, hopefully. If that's not active for your account yet, don't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that you have only one migration with any given name. If for some reason you have two different migrations with an identical name but different timestamps you will likely get an error of this sort.

The solution is to figure out which one is the correct migration and remove or rename the other.